# Determining Singularities in the Sine Function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

Determine the singularities in $f(z)=\sin(\frac3{2-z})$ and thus find the radius of convergence of the Maclaurin Series for $f(z)$.

So in this case $z=2$ is a singularity.

Also, I'm not entirely sure as to how this ties in with the Maclaurin Series.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I'll edit the post.

Comment: For the Maclaurin series: How do singularities affect Taylor expansions?

Answer (score 3):

Since $f$ is holomorphic in $D = \{z \in \mathbb{C}: 0<|z+2|\}$ you can
represent it using a Laurent series.

The Taylor series for $\sin(z)$ is 
\begin{equation}
\sin(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
\end{equation}
Therefore
\begin{equation}
\sin\left(\frac{3}{z-2}\right) = 
\frac{3}{z-2} - \frac{1}{3!} \left(\frac{3}{z-2}\right)^3 + \frac{1}{5!} \left(\frac{3}{z-2}\right)^5 - \ldots
\end{equation}
Since the principal part of the Laurent series has an infinite number of terms, $z_0 = 2$ is an essential singularity of $f$.

Moreover, let $G = \{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z| < R\}$ be an open disk. Since a Maclaurin series which converges in $G$ is holomorphic in $G$ we obtain
that $G$ cannot contain $z_0 = 2$ and therefore the radius of convergence 
of the Maclaurin series is 2.